# Nginx Rewrite working except for root directory

Tags: nginx

I'd like to pass all requests that don't match a file to a script at `/framework/root.php?path={whatever the request $uri was}`.

This works nicely for all requests except for only `/`, for example `http://localhost`.

Here is my Nginx config:

PS: Only started using Nginx coming from Apache today.

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @root;
    }

    location @root {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /framework/root.php?path=$1;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooo got it.

`try_files $uri $uri/ @root;` should be `try_files $uri @root;` without the `$uri/` part because that matches the base `/` directory.